# Get the tensors element whose counts are greater than 1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a TF tensor like this `x = tf.constant([0, 5, 5, 4, 9, 8, 0, 4])`
I want to get the elements whose counts are greater than 1, for example `[5, 4]`.
This is equivalent to numpy `.count`, like this
`[elem for elem in x if x.count(elem) > 1]`.

How can I do that in tensorflow? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tf.unique_with_counts`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique_with_counts).
It gives you a count tensor and unique values with corresponding index

```
x = tf.convert_to_tensor([1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 7, 8, 8])
y, idx, count = tf.unique_with_counts(x)

# y ==> [1, 2, 4, 7, 8]
# idx ==> [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
# count ==> [2, 1, 3, 1, 2]
```

After this, you can simply do a condition based filter

```
y_gt_1 = y[count>1]
# y_gt_1 ==> [1, 4, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
new_list=Counter([int(element) for element in x])
result=[item for item in new_list if new_list[item]>1]
```

Comment: is there any native TF function to implement this?

Comment: @swag2198 I think it is better formatted now.

Comment: @eng2019  let me check if i can find any ,until then use this snippet .